# Error when uploading PDF - Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Expression Engine's file uploader is rejecting uploaded PDF files and others. Yet the folders have the correct permissions and the file upload preferences are correct.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by Expression Engine's `XSS Filtering` setting. The filter was rejecting valid PDF files because they contained even simple URLs.

Turning this off fixed the problem.

`Admin -> Security & Privacy -> Security & Sessions` and change `Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?`

Comment: Thx bud, you saved me a lot of time tracking down the issue.